# How to see published posts with hashtag from iOS app using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, social-networking

I have an iOS app allowing people to participate to a "photo contest" by publishing a photo on Facebook with an hashtag from the app. The winner depends on the "likes" count of each post.

I thought it was possible to find all posts by searching the hashtag directly from the Facebook search bar but published posts aren't visible.

How can I make it visible?
The app is already published and the contest has started today, is there a working solution without update needed (like Facebook app configuration, ask for some permissions, ...)?

Comment: You can't and it is not allowed to incentivize posts anyway.

Comment: If I ask people to mention my page, is it going to work? "Page mentioning" permission si enought to do that ?

Comment: Having people post and mention your page or hashtag as a requirement is not allowed

Comment: Are you sure ? We are not allowed to pre-fill in the post form but if we just suggest to mention a page, it should be ok right ?

Comment: You are allowed them to suggest to mention a page. You are not allowed to require them to mention the page to be part of the competition

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll see if I can update the rules of the contest to add this suggestion. Any other idea to gather publised posts?

Comment: You can’t. And you are not even allowed to ask users to share something to take part in a competition, not even without any hashtag or mention. [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse), 4.5: _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_ – that means, if you want users to enter a competition, you are only allowed to ask them to comment/post onto your Facebook Fanpage. Asking them to share on their personal timelines is an absolute no.